# Azure CLI - Get RateCard Information

Tags: azure, billing, azure-cli, azure-billing-api

I can get RateCard information from Azure's REST API documented here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt218998.aspx

Is it possible to get the same information using Azure's command line interface?

From my research, I've only seen a command for getting usage info:

```
azure usage list [options] [reportedStartTime] [reportedEndTime]
```